# Missing ASP.Net Web Application From New Project Dialogue Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have Vs-2005 IDE where **ASP.Net Web Application**  for **C#-Application** is missing or not available on New Project Dialogue Box where the new application can be  design.

Is it possible to recover it without UnInstall and Re-Install the software of VS-2005?

Note:- **It was there on use of first time but when I started to use windows application in c# then it was disappear from the new project list. don't know why?.**

Answer (score 0):

There are more info needed like the version of the IDE. You should probably have a Visual C# Express Edition and you must probably install a Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition for solving it. But it's all an assumption...

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2005 you need to install SP1 in order to have the ASP.NET Web Application template project.